# Positive Part of a stereo jack?

Tags: switches, ground, output

Ok, so I'm building a bass/treble cut switch for a guitar pedal and on the diagram that I'm following it shows an output switch with a + label on it. Which part of the jack is that ? [image]

Also, where is the ground that I should connect the DPDT switch to?

Comment: Ground connects to ground.

Answer (score 3):

Guitars use a mono Phone Connector, TS (Tip-Sleeve) jack/plug. It could be 1/8th (3.5mm) or 1/4th inch version.

[image]

Tip is normally the audio channel, Sleeve the ground. That ground is the one the DPDT pin should be tied to.

Comment: if you look carefully it can be seen that the solder tags for tip and ring are mislableled in that image. (the contacts are correctly labeled, just the tags are transposed)

Comment: @Jasen - I corrected the picture for Passerby

Comment: @MichaelKaras, yeah, it looks correct now.

Comment: But which part is the "positive" part that I connect it to?

Comment: If you know which one is ground, that only leaves one option for positive ...